# Listen for asset modification in editor

Tags: c#, unity, assets

I would like to listen for an event that some asset (prefab, precisely) has been modified. To my surprise, there's no such event in `AssetModificationProcessor`.

Is there any way to do this in Unity?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [AssetPostProcessor](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.html) to post-process your assets in Unity Editor.

Here is an extract of the code I used in a project before.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MyPostProcessor : AssetPostprocessor {
    public delegate void PostProcessAsset();
    public static event PostProcessAsset PostProcessAssetHandler;

    public static void OnPostprocessAllAssets(
        string[] importedAssets, string[] deletedAssets, string[] movedAssets, string[] movedFromAssetPaths) {
        if (PostProcessAssetHandler != null) {
            PostProcessAssetHandler();
        }
    }
}
```

Register any functions you want to execute to the event `PostProcessAsset`.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, that will only work if you want to listen to the event from a custom editor script in an Editor folder. If you want a standard monobehavior class to respond to a post-process event, you must find another solution.